# Unable to upload/install any WordPress themes

Tags: themes

I have a version 3 installation of wordpress on my hosting package that I installed myself

Everything else so far seems ok such as posting etc, but I'm unable to install any new themes

I have tried to install a theme from clicking one of the "featured" themes, and have tried to upload a ZIP from the wordpress themes website, but each time it just hangs on "Unpacking" or "downloading" and nothing ever happens, I don't get any errors

I've noticed that under `/wp-content/uploads` I can see a zip I select for upload, its filesize seems ok

Any ideas?

Comment: I am experiencing the same behaviour with plugins, however I was able to install an AdSense plugin ok.. :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem most notably occurs on systems running PHP4.  If you can, upgrade your server to PHP5 (if you're on a hosted server, there's usually a setting in cPanel or whatever administrative tool you have to switch from PHP4 to PHP5).

Comment: Correct, creating a simple phpinfo file exposed version as PHP Version 4.4.9. +1 and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also check the permissions on the affected directories. It doesnt sound like thats the issue, but they have a habit of cropping up in WP